# NGRX changes subscribing. What's the best way for ngrx store-subscribe in multiple components?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have an angular project with the NGRX store. My NGRX store used by multiple components at the same time (over 7 components).

Should I subscribe for the store changes in all of that components (i think that can lead for loss of performance)? Or I should subscribe only on the TOP component and then pass ngrx changes to child components by @Inputs?

Comment: it doesn't metter. from this points of view you won't have even a 1% difference. all the pitfalls will be in your custom code and sometimes in recreating a lot of html, which also depends on how good you are using the framework. observables subscriptions are cheap, and angular change detection in most of the cases is good enough, so you won't notice it is happening

Comment: I don't think ther'll be a significant performance difference at all also. But subscribing them in all components are better i guess, because in that case you are dependent for the data you need, but in other case you are dependent to the parent component which is less maintanable i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer really is "it depends", but the "container-presenter" or "smart-dumb" architectural model basically says you have a parent which deals with getting data from the store and passing it to its children via @Inputs. This allows you to separate display logic from business logic, and is what I recommend most of the time.

Commenters have said that there will be no performance issues. That isn't necessarily true, especially as your app becomes more complex.